# Как передать в конструктор класса DateTime строку, содержащую только год?

Tags: php, datetime

```php
    $date = new DateTime("2000");

    echo $date->format('Y');

    //выводит 2017
```

Почему так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формат "Только год" не подхватывается.
Создадим же его через [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y", "2000");
echo $date-> format("Y"); // 2000
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!